# How to disable selected lines by the char "#" in one time?

Tags: python, keyboard, shortcut

Whatever is the code, i'm just searching for the way to disable some lines directly in one time by char "#".

For example, i have this code :

```py
import json

def get(user):
    try:
        with open("tokens.json") as f:
            data_token = json.load(f)
            f.close()
        return str(data_token["tokens"][user])
    except:
        return False

def check(user, token_key):
    with open("tokens.json", 'r') as f:
        data_tokens = json.load(f)
        f.close()
    for ids, tokens in data_tokens["tokens"].items():
        if str(ids) == str(user):
            if int(tokens) == int(token_key):


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get("User1"))
```

And i temporary want to disable my fonction named "check()" because it makes a error right now :

```py
import json

def get(user):
    try:
        with open("tokens.json") as f:
            data_token = json.load(f)
            f.close()
        return str(data_token["tokens"][user])
    except:
        return False

#def check(user, token_key):
#    with open("tokens.json", 'r') as f:
#        data_tokens = json.load(f)
#        f.close()
#    for ids, tokens in data_tokens["tokens"].items():
#        if str(ids) == str(user):
#            if int(tokens) == int(token_key):


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get("User1"))
```

I already seen some guys doing that and i wanted to know how to do.

Thanks ;)

Comment: This is more related to IDE you are using. In Pycharm/Jupyter you can use Ctrl and `/` Key to comment the selected lines

Comment: What software are you using to code?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm to code.

Comment: Oh yess, thanks a lot, it's working !